# How can I use subprocess.Popen in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, benchmarking

I'm trying to use subprocess.Popen to run a command, and I've chosen this over subprocess.run, as I need the output from the command printed to the shell.

I'm calling the commands in a for loop, and modifying the environment for each iteration, but python only runs the first command, and not the other 6.

I'm pretty sure this is a bug as I can't find anything else like this, but I thought I'd check before I submit the "bug".

The relevant code looks like this

```
input_file = Path("input.json").open()

for thread in threads:
    new_env = default_env
    new_env["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = str(thread)
    print("Starting run for {} threads".format(thread))
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        benchmark_command, env=new_env, stdin=input_file, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    lines = []
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line.decode(), end='')
    results.append(Result(lines, thread))
    print("Completed run for {} threads".format(thread))
```

and the current output is this

```
❯ python python/plot_results.py
Starting run for 1 threads
<expected output from running command>
Completed run for 1 threads
Starting run for 2 threads
Completed run for 2 threads
Starting run for 4 threads
Completed run for 4 threads
Starting run for 8 threads
Completed run for 8 threads
Starting run for 16 threads
Completed run for 16 threads
Starting run for 32 threads
Completed run for 32 threads
Starting run for 56 threads
Completed run for 56 threads
```

but should look like this

```
❯ python python/plot_results.py
Starting run for 1 threads
<expected output from running command>
Completed run for 1 threads
Starting run for 2 threads
<expected output from running command>
Completed run for 2 threads
Starting run for 4 threads
<expected output from running command>
Completed run for 4 threads
Starting run for 8 threads
<expected output from running command>
Completed run for 8 threads
Starting run for 16 threads
<expected output from running command>
Completed run for 16 threads
Starting run for 32 threads
<expected output from running command>
Completed run for 32 threads
Starting run for 56 threads
<expected output from running command>
Completed run for 56 threads
```

Comment: `input_file`  is presumably an open file object.  The first run of a subprocess will likely consume all of it, leaving the file positioned at the very end.  Subsequent runs will have no input data to work on.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, that was it! The reason I wasn't getting any errors from the benchmark command is that it opens an input stream, and doesn't time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @jasonharper's suggestion, I needed to make a new open file object for each iteration.

```
input_file = Path("input.json")

for thread in threads:
    new_env = default_env
    new_env["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = str(thread)
    print("Starting run for {} threads".format(thread))
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        benchmark_command, env=new_env, stdin=input_file.open(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    lines = []
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line.decode(), end='')
    results.append(Result(lines, thread))
    print("Completed run for {} threads".format(thread))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would say that unless your level of expertise in the language is far beyond senior, or the nature of your problem is extremely uncommon, it is unlikely that your problem is a bug, and rather, it is probably some misconception you have regarding how the language is doing things.

In your case, `Popen` does not block your main thread. Your problem is that the main thread is starting all processes... and eventually starts reading output from stdout and prints it.

Simple solution would be using `subprocess.check_output` to wait the commands to finish, but it doesn't allow `env` parameter so we'll go for `communicate()` method after the call to Popen, which will also block your main thread and wait for the process to terminate:

```py
for thread in threads:
    new_env = default_env
    new_env["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = str(thread)
    print("Starting run for {} threads".format(thread))
    output = subprocess.Popen(
        benchmark_command, env=new_env, stdin=input_file, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = output.communicate()
    lines = []
    for line in stdout:
        print(line.decode(), end='')
    results.append(Result(lines, thread))
    print("Completed run for {} threads".format(thread))
```